# How to import external library from [tomcat_home]/lib in TOMCAT

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I'm trying to apply external library in java project.

According to the API documentation, it shouldn't be located under reloadable classpath like `WEB-INF/classes` or `WEB-INF/lib` and the easiest way to apply API is put the .jar file into `[tomcat home]/lib` and restart tomcat.
So I put the jar file into `[tomcat home]/lib` folder and import the API on java class.
But error occurred when I run the server. It seems the API not imported.

```
2022-08-09 11:08:36,499  WARN [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '[api class name]': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
        [api name] cannot be resolved
```

Do I need more settings?

Answer (score 0):

**#SOLVED**

I just placed jar file only into tomcat server not local because the API is available
only in operation server.

So I add jar file on my eclipse (`Project Right Click - Build Path - Configure Build Path - Add External JARs`) and then deploy project as WAR.